# Convert Rails SQL output to valid psql statements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Active Job creates the following SQL on placing a job in its queue.

```
INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("queue", "handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["queue", "mailers"], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\n  job_id: 189ce295-1da8-47f5-9933-1b5657554731\n  queue_name: mailers\n  arguments:\n  - UserMailer\n  - register_success\n  - deliver_now\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/User/1\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/Order/294\n  - token: 561e6309deb2b9.72817606\n    number: 123\n    expiration: '2025-10-14'\n"], ["run_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140078"], ["created_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408"]]
```

How would I modify this to work as a raw SQL query? I thought that the rails output was supposed to be valid sql, but I get an error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["queue", ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is using placeholders. so you would need to replace the $x with the values
so

```
INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("queue", "handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["queue", "mailers"], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\n  job_id: 189ce295-1da8-47f5-9933-1b5657554731\n  queue_name: mailers\n  arguments:\n  - UserMailer\n  - register_success\n  - deliver_now\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/User/1\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/Order/294\n  - token: 561e6309deb2b9.72817606\n    number: 123\n    expiration: '2025-10-14'\n"], ["run_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140078"], ["created_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408"]]
```

would be come

```
INSERT INTO "delayed_jobs" ("queue", "handler", "run_at", "created_at", "updated_at")
 VALUES (
 'mailers',
 '--- !ruby/object:ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper\njob_data:\n  job_class: ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\n  job_id: 189ce295-1da8-47f5-9933-1b5657554731\n  queue_name: mailers\n  arguments:\n  - UserMailer\n  - register_success\n  - deliver_now\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/User/1\n  - _aj_globalid: gid://hub/Order/294\n  - token: 561e6309deb2b9.72817606\n    number: 123\n    expiration: '2025-10-14'\n',
 '2015-10-14 14:13:30.140078', 
 '2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408',
 '2015-10-14 14:13:30.140408'
) RETURNING "id"
```

Comment: oops, bad job on the cut and paste,  fixed thanks @muistooshort

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `ActiveRecord` object that generated that database call, you can use the [`to_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_sql) method to get the SQL query.